# How to Update QGIS 3.16 ltr to 3.20 lsb in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I would like to update/upgrade/change from QGIS 3.16 to 3.20.
Steps for this process cannot be found for Ubuntu (currently 20.04)

Is it possible to update QGIS to lsb without losing settings in Ubuntu?
Is it as simple as updating the repository and installing?
What are the steps?

Comment: Change your [repo source](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#repositories) from https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr to https://qgis.org/ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works